# Why does the female changeling always appear in human form?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

The [female changeling](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Female_Changeling) nearly always appears in a female-Odo-like-version. **I understand that she uses that form when negotiating with the Federation or meeting Odo, which is explained in other questions and answers. But that is not my question.** She even keeps this form when Odo (or someone else from the Federation) is not around.

Why does she not take the appearance of a lifeform of the Gamma Quadrant (Jem'Hadar, Vorta, ...) or at least the form of allied species (Cardassian, Breen), when only together with them? Before coming to the Alpha Quadrant, they did not know how humans looked, so they must have another appearance when communicating with species there. Why did she not use this appearance? I remember that they replaced Martok with a changeling, so they should have the ability to take form of their allies or minions.

[image]

Is this ever explained in the series?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "female" mean for the Female Changeling?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103136/what-does-female-mean-for-the-female-changeling)

Comment: @richard: i dont see the duplicate here. I want to know why she keeps the form when odo is not around, i did not see this explained in your linked question (or the question linked there). But i only read the questions and answers, not all comments...

Comment: I think [Uncle Mikey's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103647/20774) deals with this perfectly; because the changeling is consistently played by the same actor.

Comment: Hm, i dont see that, she could also be masked as cardassian, vorta or something else for some scenes, i think the effort would have been the same, and also it is an out of universe answer. Its clear that she choosed that appearance when she meet odo, but not why she keeps it when hes is not around. But well, we let the community decide, i hope i get an answer before this gets closed (if it get sclosed), because i would like to know and see no answer in the "duplicate"...

Comment: I think it's reasonably likely to get closed.

Comment: Masking her as a Cardassian would confuse audiences, many of whom aren't watching avidly. You need to dress your characters in a consistent way or audiences lose track of why they're doing the things they do.

Comment: In-universe, masking as a Breen would be impossible, because nobody knows what they look like.

Comment: @kl78:   Nitpick: She's not in human form because her appearance is based on Odo whose appearance is based on a Bajoran ([this guy](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Mora_Pol))

Comment: @thepopmachine: as i stated multiple times, i know that, but the question was why she kept the form when odo was not around and not took the form of some of there allies or minions instead, like they would do in gamma quadrant when they communicate with vorta, Jem'Hadar, etc.). E.G. Its like i could shapeshift and take form of a wolf when i met them, then i go live with jackals but still keep my wolf form. But escoce gave a good explanation for this in his comments...

Comment: Appearing openly in the form of a solid would be beneath her dignity, but she needs to be able to deal with the solids under her command.  Odo's form is a perfect compromise: able to speak, similar enough to solids to reassure them somewhat, but different enough that she could not be mistaken for a "mere" solid.

Comment: @kl78, I'm only pointing out she never appeared in human form, just Bajoran or humanoid.   I said it was a nitpick...

Comment: “Before coming to the Alpha Quadrant, they did not know how humans looked” — We first see “the” female changeling when Odo travels to the Gamma Quadrant and is drawn to their homeworld, and she seems to mimic his appearance. After that, I figure she decided she’d stick with that form when dealing with solids — why bother creating different forms for interacting with different races? It’s not like her Odo mimicry is particularly human-looking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the other changelings look like Dr Mora?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28013/why-do-the-other-changelings-look-like-dr-mora)

Comment: The possible duplicate flagged earlier isn't really a dup, as has been said. However, there is a linked question within that one that does seem to be a dup of this one and has some excellent answers explaining why the other shapeshifters pick a similar look to Odo.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding here is that you think she's going for "human." Like other's have said and have linked an answer, she's going for "Odo."

Answer (score 3):

If I recall, the changelings didn't trust the solids enough to "not appear" humanoid. Odo himself is very self conscious about being seen in "his bucket" or otherwise during those times he just can't maintain his humanoid shape. Very few people are invited to see changelings in their natural state, Kira being one of those few.

Comment: yes, but why does she not take a Vorta, cardassian, etc. form when only together with there minions and allies, but the human form, which is the enemy... If they dont trust the solids enough to not appear in humanoid form, they must have appearad to the vorta and Jem'Hadar in an humanid form  when first encoutering them in gamma quadrant, why dont use it now, but only odos human-like form, even if he is not around...

Comment: She doesn't take a human form, she and they in general take a loosely humanoid form. Most aliens in Star Trek are humanoids from an appearance point of view. If she approximated more cardassian maybe she'd have more prominent eye sockets or something, but it would be so vague I don't think you'd even notice.

Comment: Hm, ok, can you post a quote or reference to the information your last comment? I remember that only odo had the problems and she took that form because of him when she first mets him, then never changes the form in the rest of the series even when he is not around, which is strange for me, because none of there allies are humans... But if this their generell and only humanoid appearance, you are right and i will accept your answer, but never heard this before...

Comment: They also replaced martok with a changeling, so they could do a klingon, why not a cardassian?

Comment: No, Odo didn't have a problem. I can't come up with a quote, and wouldn't even begin to have the time to really hunt one down, but we can extrapolate from what we DO know. Early on in the series Odo is asked about his more fluid approximation of human form. He says he can take on a more detailed form, but that it is more work to sustain and will tire him out sooner. Just because she chooses the same approximation is by no means just simple diplomacy or deference. The changelings would NEVER admit a weakness. Additionally, and again most aliens are of humanoid form anyway.

Comment: To continue, if she chose a different humanoid alien form, the differences are really only in the details. The form the changelings chose is quite easily an "approximation" of all the humanoid shaped races.

Comment: Ah,ok, your last comment is something i can understand. Still wonder how one of them could hold martoks form for so long without detection then, but that is another question. But i guess the creators of the series did not think about all details of this, and mainly out-of-universe reasons are responsible for (imo) some strange "plot-holes" with the changelings.

Comment: How long did _martok_ have to hold his form?

Comment: cant remember exactly, but according to memory alpha he was not detected for more then 1 and a half year: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Martok_%28Changeling%29 . But i dont know how often he had the option to regenerate during this time.

Comment: Well that's what I mean, not the duration of the insurgence, but how long at a time.

Comment: I guess this was never told. I would think that under some cicumstances he had to hold at least the whole day and be sure that noone entered his room at night, but that is only a guess... If you edit the "approximation comment" in your answer i will accept. If you could even find a quote for this, it would be even nicer. But i guess this question will be closed as duplicate soon anyway, although i do not understand why. But i can live with your explanation, although without a quote i am not sure if this was really the reason or they did not think about this at all, but at least it makes sense

Answer (score 2):

There are countless examples that show the changelings despise all solids; the form she chooses is a basic humanoid form (no specifics features from any one species). What you're asking is the same as why didn't Sisko get pointy ears when he meets with the Romulans - it's insulting to both species (especially when the Founders think other species are lower life forms, and have no desire to try to make 'lower life forms' more  comfortable).

They are *proud* of being different and superior; the basic form allows communication whilst simultaneously emphasizing she is a 'god among insects'; she won't belittle herself by assuming a form to fit in.

She says this to Odo, implying death was preferable to being a humanoid:

> Female Shapeshifter: Ah, poor Odo. Perhaps we should have killed you. It would have been far less cruel. [After the Founders have turned Odo into a "solid"]

And this (again she's proud of being different) - the human form is only to interact, nothing more; she wants to control solids, not be like them:

> Major Kira: You belong to the Dominion, don't you?
>
> Female Shapeshifter: Belong to it? Major, the Changelings *are* the Dominion.
>
> Odo: [understanding] You are the Founders!
>
> Female Shapeshifter: Ironic, isn't it? The hunted now control the destinies of hundreds of other races.
>
> Odo: But... why control anyone?
>
> Female Shapeshifter: Because what you can control, can't hurt you.
>
> Odo: How do you justify the deaths of so many people?
>
> Female Shapeshifter: The Solids have always been a threat to us. That's the only justification we need.
>
> Odo: But these Solids have never harmed you. They travel the galaxy in order to expand their knowledge, just as you once did.
>
> Female Shapeshifter: The Solids are nothing like us.
>
> Odo: No - I suppose they're not. And neither am I.

And finally the only time she takes full humanoid appearance is to understand Odo not wanting to join them:

> Odo: But why lead us here? Why replace Major Kira?
>
> Female Shapeshifter: I needed to understand why you chose to live with the solids rather than your own people. I suspected it had something to do with Major Kira. Now, I'm certain of it.
>
> Female Shapeshifter: Save her, if it suits you. But it won't make any difference. She is never going to love you. How could she? You are a Changeling.

This all points to them wanting to be different, being proud of it, and having no need to belittle themselves by pleasing solids.

One more thing too: if you were a politician going to China I'm pretty sure you would not squint your eyes to look like the locals (might not go down too well).

Comment: Could you explain the downvote please?

Comment: No idea about the down vote, but this bit — “What your'e asking is the same as why didn't Sisko get pointy ears when he meets with the Romulans” — doesn’t quite seem accurate.

Comment: Oh! Also your last sentence sounds a wee bit racist.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - That was one of the reasons I downvoted. The bit about Sisko was just puzzling

Comment: That's what I was trying to point out, imitating features of another race (or nation) could be interpreted wrongly as being insulting/racist, even if its a changeling doing it (and sticking to the generic humanoid would prevent such misinterpretation). It only sounds racist because I used an example that people could associate with today, I'm sure sure sure other species would view it the same. No offence is intended!!

Answer (score -2):

First and foremost because she is *the*, not merely *a* or *any other* female changeling.

We might, from 'our' point of view, compare her to the Borg Queen… very much like and at the same time utterly unlike her minions.

Part of Mrs Changeling's function is to appear to every-race other in either quadrant not as an individual with anything like Odo's whimsical ideas of what form to take when, but as an icon; a thematic image of how changelings might like to be seen, underpinned with various religiously significant memes and tropes.

She keeps that form when no-one from the Federation is around for reasons similar to how and why actors stay 'in role' when they're off screen or stage.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold statements about her intentions?

Comment: Valorum, that query refutes what I tried to put across, being that 'her intentions' don't exist, as such. Do you doubt that she, or anything about her, is meant to represent the Link as a whole?

I said nothing about her intentions and of course I back up those bold statements only by pointing out that they are half the point of Western literature… not something to explore here but do raise a specific Question. 

I merely watched the episodes and considered how general principles of culture, ethics, literature, religion, philosophy and the like might apply.

Can't you do that?

Comment: That's a very long-winded way of saying "no".

Comment: Sorry, Valorum. I'm glad I'm not responsible for your background knowledge, and I'm not!

That was a polite way of saying 'why not watch those episodes again, consider them in much more detail and if they lose you, Post any queries here?'

Comment: So your evidence is, if I can paraphrase, every episode in which this character appears or is mentioned.

Comment: That reads rather strangely and fairly clearly, paraphrasing isn't really your thing.

Still if you must put it that way yes, of course: in your terms, the evidence is every episode in which she appears… I have no knowledge of or interest in episodes which merely mention her and I do mind that you seem to be trying not to address the issue. If you feel the general principles of culture, ethics, literature, religion, philosophy and the like do not apply to Star Trek, why not just say so?